How can I query an embedded language using tree-sitter?
For example, if I have the following markdown file:
# Title


``` r
# Comment
123
```

Treesitter gives me the following language tree:
(document ; [0, 0] - [8, 0]
  (section ; [0, 0] - [8, 0]
    (atx_heading ; [0, 0] - [1, 0]
      (atx_h1_marker) ; [0, 0] - [0, 1]
      heading_content: (inline ; [0, 2] - [0, 7]
        (inline))) ; [0, 2] - [0, 7]
    (fenced_code_block ; [3, 0] - [7, 0]
      (fenced_code_block_delimiter) ; [3, 0] - [3, 3]
      (info_string ; [3, 4] - [3, 5]
        (language)) ; [3, 4] - [3, 5]
      (block_continuation) ; [4, 0] - [4, 0]
      (code_fence_content ; [4, 0] - [6, 0]
        (program ; [4, 0] - [6, 0]
          (comment) ; [4, 0] - [4, 9]
          (float)) ; [5, 0] - [5, 3]
        (block_continuation) ; [5, 0] - [5, 0]
        (block_continuation)) ; [6, 0] - [6, 0]
      (fenced_code_block_delimiter)) ; [6, 0] - [6, 3]
    (fenced_code_block ; [7, 0] - [8, 0]
      (fenced_code_block_delimiter)))) ; [7, 0] - [7, 4]

As shown in the tree, comment is recognised as the node type for the first line in the R code block. However, I haven't been able to write a query to match this comment, since R is an embedded language within the tree.
Here's the query I'm using:
(comment) @comment

This gives an error Invalid node type "comment".
As far as I can tell, the tree-sitter documentation for injected languages only describes how to inject a language itself, but not how to query a language which is already embedded.
